# How should a singleton client use singleton?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I am not looking for what is a singleton. There are hundreds of links out. I have not found good examples of `client of singleton`. Example consider a Singleton class ( whose internals are not important at all)

I want to use this object. Where / how woud client use it ? Should it be used in a constructor  ? static initializer ?

```
Singleton tmp = Singleton.getInstance( );
```

I would appreciate any `sample examples` of `singleton clients` ??

Comment: I'm not sure there *are* any "best practices" for **using** a singleton.

Comment: Using a singleton is not a best practice to begin with =\

Comment: ok, can anyone please provide me with an example ?

Comment: String tmp = Singleton.getInstance( ).doStuff();

Comment: @tom i agree, but i mean is where / how  ? in constructor ? in static initializer ? could this be expanded more than a mere single line ?

Comment: It really won't make a difference.

Comment: You could look at dependency injection @Singleton

Comment: Why do you want to use a singleton? What does this get you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Singleton Pattern is when you create an object that is designed that there be a single instance of that object in the program.  As a client, you have to get a pointer to an instance.  You have only four options:

1. Hold a reference in a static variable and initialize by 'lazy evaluation' that is, test for null, and then initialize when null.  After that the value is set.
2. Hold a reference in a static variable and initialize at static initialization time.  Are you sure that the singleton it ready at that time?  This is a concern.
3. Hold reference in local variable, and initialize every time with call to getInstance().
4. Don't use a variable at all and call in the method chain.  If only one reference for one call is needed, this is fine.

In general, getInstance should be quite efficient, and there should be little reason to hold a copy of the reference in your own static.  In a sense, your static is duplicating the job of the singleton class which also has to have a static.  A single shouldn't ever change, but if it ever did, you would be left holding a stale reference.  Option 4 is OK if you need only one call, but this pattern encourages inefficiency when multiple calls are needed.  So, for all these reasons I believe you should use option 3 and get the instance every time.

There are times that this singleton pattern is appropriate.  There are also times that it is not appropriate, and a class with static methods is more efficient.  How can you tell when and when not to use the Singleton pattern?  Here is a blog post I made last week on the subject:

http://agiletribe.purplehillsbooks.com/2013/10/08/dont-abuse-singleton-pattern/

Comment: An amazing link too :)